# Get current currency symbol in Magento2

Tags: magento, currency, symbols, magento2

How can I write the code for printing cart total with currency symbol in a .phtml file in Magento2?

Comment: Please add some code or show us what have you searched so far

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
protected $_currency;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,        
    array $data = []
)
{           
    $this->_currency = $currency;       
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get currency symbol for current locale and currency code
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
{
    return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
}
```

Comment: How can I get like US$?

Comment: What you are looking for resides here Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface in getCurrencySymbol(). Create a instance of it and call like this $this->priceCurrency->getCurrencySymbol()

Answer (score 5):

This is what really worked for me to get the **current currency symbol**:

```
protected $_priceCurrency;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
  array $data = []
)
{           
  $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
  parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get current currency symbol
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
{
  return $this->_priceCurrency->getCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
}
```

---

Another method could be the following

```
protected $_localeCurrency;

protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
  array $data = []
)
{           
  $this->_localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
  $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
  parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get current currency symbol
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
{
  $code = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
  return $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($code)->getSymbol();
}
```

Comment: How can I get like US$?

Answer (score 2):

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;
/**
 * @var StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_modelStoreManagerInterface;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface
 */
protected $_localeCurrency;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
    StoreManagerInterface $modelStoreManagerInterface,   
    CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,    
    array $data = []
)
{           
    $this->_modelStoreManagerInterface = $modelStoreManagerInterface;
    $this->_localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;   
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Get currency symbol for current locale and currency code
 *
 * @return string
 */ 
public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
{
    $currencyCode = $this->_modelStoreManagerInterface->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    $currencySymbol = $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($currencyCode)->getSymbol();
    return $currencySymbol;
}
```

Comment: How can I get like US$?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');

    echo $currencysymbol->getCurrencySymbol();
?>
```

Comment: Using the object manager directly to get objects is frowned upon, right?

Comment: Yes consider using dependency injection instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currencysymbol = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\Currency');
echo $currencysymbol->getCurrencySymbol();
```

But it's not a standard method. You need to inject **Magento\Directory\Model\Currency** and then use it.

Comment: It's absolutely not a standard and should not be used. Honestly I can't understand why you suggest such a solution when you - obviously - know the correct way by dependency injection.

Comment: I have mentioned that already and have mentioned the correct method as well. It was just a solution that could be considered ad will work fine without any sort of error. And nothing is wrong with this solution, it's just about objectManager which is not recommended as per magento standards.

Answer (score -1):

To get the Currency Symbol:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

$price =  1000; //Your Price

$formattedPrice = $priceHelper->currency($price, true, false);
```